# Laravel saving without updating timestamp

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I understand that there are already plenty of identical questions posted on stack overflow however what I want to clarify is why does method 1 not work for me but method 2 does.

I am trying to update an existing entry without affecting the timestamps

**Method 1**

```
$manual_ticket->status = "Queued";
$manual_ticket->initiator_id = null;
$manual_ticket->save(['timestamps' => false]);
```

**Method 2**

```
$manual_ticket->status = "Queued";
$manual_ticket->initiator_id = null;
$manual_ticket->timestamps = false;
$manual_ticket->save();
```

*Laravel Version* = 5.5

Comment: since laravel 5.3, timestamp option you are using in the first method is dropped. so your first method didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

when you call [save](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/349b5cc7f2f18e1d0d6ac7f22994f7c214085c3b/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L969) method from model. I will call [finishSave](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/349b5cc7f2f18e1d0d6ac7f22994f7c214085c3b/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1033) method. But finishSave method will only accept `touch` as array key and won't respect any other array key that you pass. You can use [saveQuietly](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/349b5cc7f2f18e1d0d6ac7f22994f7c214085c3b/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L956) method to save model without raising any model events